# Angular 15 SSR - Component 'f' is not resolved: - templateUrl: ../../templates/header/header.component.html

Tags: webpack, angular-universal, jsdom, angular15, angular-ssr

I am trying to implement Angular Universal to an Angular 15 application that uses window and jquery. I have added the JSDOM package to use window object in server.ts and also added webpack.server.config.ts file for transpiling files like "canvas.node". The build gets generated successfully with "npm run build:ssr" and when I serve the application with "npm run serve:ssr" then It says **Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000** as expected but when I hit this url in browser then It throws the following error:

```
Error: Component 'f' is not resolved:
 - templateUrl: ../../templates/header/header.component.html
Did you run and wait for 'resolveComponentResources()'?
    at Function.get (path_to_application/dist/server.js:2:1798018)
    at Fe (path_to_application/dist/server.js:2:1631172)
    at Aa (path_to_application/dist/server.js:2:1678967)
    at path_to_application/dist/server.js:2:1679384
    at path_to_application/dist/server.js:2:1652886
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pi (path_to_application/dist/server.js:2:1652849)
    at path_to_application/dist/server.js:2:1652878
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pi (path_to_application/dist/server.js:2:1652849)
```

The header.component.html file does exists at the specified location. However, I have also tried to place the html file at the location same as header.component.ts and also changed from templateUrl: ../../templates/header/header.component.html to templateUrl: ./header.component.html  but I am still getting the same error. Below is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "productName": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "myapp",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run myapp:serve-ssr",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --output-hashing=none && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.config.js",
    "prerender": "ng run myapp:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.9",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.2.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.1",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "canvas": "^2.11.2",
    "core-js": "^3.26.1",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "electron-log": "^4.4.8",
    "electron-progressbar": "^2.0.1",
    "electron-updater": "^5.3.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.2",
    "jsdom": "^22.0.0",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "mock-browser": "^0.92.14",
    "ng-marquee": "^9.5.0",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-electron": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-malihu-scrollbar": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^15.0.2",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^11.1.1",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.6.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "regexp-replace-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.5",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1302.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^15.2.4",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^15.2.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2020": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "electron": "^13.6.6",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "grunt": "^1.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^2.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-exec": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-http": "^2.3.3",
    "grunt-string-replace": "^1.3.3",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^11.1.0",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.2",
    "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "string-replace-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-plugin-hash-output": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.7",
    "utf-8-validate": "^6.0.3"
  }
}
```

**server.ts**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';

enableProdMode();

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  
  const template = readFileSync(join(distFolder, 'index.html')).toString();
  const constants = readFileSync(join(distFolder, 'constants' , 'constants.js')).toString();
  /*
    "constants.js" file contains the following line:
    window.MY_CONSTANTS = { APP_TITLE: 'Hello World' }
  */
  const dom = new JSDOM(template+`<script>`+constants+`</script>`, {runScripts: "dangerously", url: 'http://localhost:4000'});
  const win  = dom.window;
  
  global['window'] = <any>win;
  global['MY_CONSTANTS'] = win['MY_CONSTANTS'];
  global['document'] = win.document;
  global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
  global['Node'] = win.Node;
  global['Text'] = win.Text;
  global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
  global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
  global['localStorage'] = localStorage;

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

**app.server.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

**webpack.server.config.ts**

```
const path = require('path');
const _root = path.resolve(__dirname);
const ngw = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const webpack = require('webpack');
function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
}
module.exports = {
  entry: { server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/ ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.(cjs|cts|mjs|mts)$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    compact: false,
                    plugins: ['@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel'],
                },
            },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /.*\.(jsx|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: '@ngtools/webpack',
      },
      {
          test: /\.node$/,
          use: 'node-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ngw.AngularWebpackPlugin({
      tsconfig: root('tsconfig.server.json')
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

**tsconfig.server.json**

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jquery",
      "mcustomscrollbar"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "e2e/*.e2e-spec.ts",
    "e2e/app.po.ts",
    "**/test.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": false,
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
}
```

**Note: I am not using BrowserTransferStateModule and ServerTransferStateModule as they are deprecated in Angular 15.**